# How to direct print a pdf in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, printing

Iv created a POS app. When a transaction is done the receipt comes from the backend as a pdf and I want to allow it to print in a thermal printer. Most packages create the receipt than print, but I already have a pdf receipt and I want to print receipt directly from my app ,any help?

expecting print receipt directly.

Answer (score 1):

use this package - blue_thermal_printer

```
import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/blue_thermal_printer.dart';

// Initialize the Bluetooth printer instance
BlueThermalPrinter bluetooth = BlueThermalPrinter.instance;

// Search for available Bluetooth devices
List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];

void initBluetooth() {
  bluetooth.getBondedDevices().then((List<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices) {
    setState(() {
      devices = bondedDevices;
    });
  });
}
```

---

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Function to print a PDF receipt
Future<void> printReceipt() async {
  // Load the PDF file
  Uint8List pdfBytes = // Load your PDF content here

  // Connect to the selected printer
  if (bluetooth.isConnected) {
    // Send the PDF data to the printer
    final result = await bluetooth.printCustom(pdfBytes, PaperSize.mm80);

    if (result != '1') {
      print('Printing failed');
    } else {
      print('Printing success');
    }
  } else {
    print('Printer not connected');
  }
}
```

---

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    printReceipt();
  },
  child: Text('Print Receipt'),
)
```

Comment: it's work for Bluetooth connected printer but I have an InnerPrinter(Android POS Terminal Handheld). So it's not work for me.

Comment: ok use this - https://pub.dev/packages/printing